# Using python, I need to average value based on two keys in two columns from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 3 columns

```
TMC, EPOCH, Time
11C12, 1, 24
11C12, 1, 34
11C12, 2, 56
11C12, 2, 78
11C13, 1, 56
11C13, 2, 45
11C13, 2, 64
11C13, 3, 32
11C13, 3, 28
```

Now I want to have average.py file which calculates average of time for each combination of TMC, EPOCH and write that to a txt or csv file

The desired output is:

```
TMC, EPOCH, Average Time
11C12, 1, average value 
11C12, 2, average value
11C13, 1, average value
11C13, 2, average value
11C13, 3, average value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` to group the elements using the forst two columns as the key and appending the times then average and write to the new csv:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("in.csv") as f, open("average.csv", "w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    head = next(f)
    out.write(head)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        d[tuple(row[:2])].append(int(row[-1]))

    for k, v in d.items():
        out.write("{},{},{}\n".format(k[0], k[1], sum(v, 0.0) / len(v)))
```

Output:

```
TMC,EPOCH,Time
11C12,1,29.0
11C12,2,67.0
11C13,1,56.0
11C13,2,54.5
11C13,3,30.0
```

If you want to keep the order the elements are first seen you can use an `OrderedDict`:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("in.csv") as f, open("average.csv", "w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    d = OrderedDict()
    head = next(f)
    out.write(head)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        d.setdefault(tuple(row[:2]), []).append(int(row[-1]))

    for k, v in d.items():
        out.write("{},{},{}\n".format(k[0], k[1], sum(v, 0.0) / len(v)))
```